# How to remove an elif from a loop when the elif is used once

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

```
def AI():
    if(board[0][0] == board[0][1] and board[0][0] != ""):
        computer_putThing(0,2)
    elif(board[0][2] == board[0][1] and board[0][2] != ""):
        computer_putThing(0,0)
    elif(board[1][0] == board[1][1] and board[1][0] != ""):
        computer_putThing(1,2)
```

I am making a tic tac toe AI and these are a snippit of the conditions it uses to place it's piece. Because multiple conditions can occur in one game, I want to be able to remove or skip over an elif after the first time it is used. Otherwise it only gets to the first statement and doesn't use the rest of the statements.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to check if the computer has already placed a piece where you are trying to place the piece. E.G. for your first if it would look something like this:

```
if(board[0][0] == board[0][1] and board[0][0] != "" and board[0,2] != ""):
    computer_putThing(0,2)
```

Of course this is assuming that `computer_putThing(int,int)` simply changes the array at the position of its aruments